# How to show that for $a,b\in \mathbb{C}: |a-b|=|1-a\overline{b}| \Leftrightarrow |a|=1 \, \lor \, |b|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How to show that for $a,b\in \mathbb{C}: |a-b|=|1-a\overline{b}|
>  \Leftrightarrow |a|=1 \, \lor \, |b|=1$

I defined $a:=x+iy$ and $b:=u+iv$ which resulted in quite an algebra mess. Is there a simpler method to solve such statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a-b|=|1-a\overline{b}|$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow(a-b)(\overline{a}-\overline{b})=(1-a\overline{b})(1-\overline{a}b)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (a\overline{a}-1)(b\overline{b}-1)=0$$